# Accent characters in a regex

Tags: php, regex

I am using this regex to be able to accept accent characters

```
/^([\p{L}a-zA-Z ,-]*)$/i
```

When i test my regex on this website : http://rubular.com/r/MRESYEGO2d
everything is ok, but when i use the same regex in my php its not working.

```
$alphaNumCity = "/^([\p{L}a-zA-Z0-9 ,-]*)$/i";
if (preg_match($alphaNumCity, $champ)) {
    echo "<label for='tags'>Villes<span style='color:red;'>*</span></label><input id='tags' name='businessVille' value='".$champ."' required />";
} else {
    echo "<label for='tags'>Villes<span style='color:red;'>(entrer un nom de ville valide)*</span></label><input id='tags' name='businessVille' required />";
    $valide = false;
}
```

This code is going in the else.

I don't understand why its working here http://rubular.com/r/MRESYEGO2d and not in my code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [unicode flag](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) (or unicode modifier):

```
/^([\p{L}a-zA-Z ,-]*)$/iu
```

Answer (score 1):

The unicode flag "u", `/^([\p{L}a-zA-Z0-9 ,-]*)$/iu`, comes with some notes:

> Regarding the validity of a UTF-8 string when using the /u pattern
>   modifier, some things to be aware of;
>
> 1. If the pattern itself contains an invalid UTF-8 character, you get an error (as mentioned in the docs above - "UTF-8 validity of the
>      pattern is checked since PHP 4.3.5"
> 2. When the subject string contains invalid UTF-8 sequences / codepoints, it basically result in a "quiet death" for the preg_*
>      functions, where nothing is matched but without indication that the
>      string is invalid UTF-8
> 3. PCRE regards five and six octet UTF-8 character sequences as valid (both in patterns and the subject string) but these are not supported
>      in Unicode ( see section 5.9 "Character Encoding" of the "Secure
>      Programming for Linux and Unix HOWTO" - can be found at
>      http://www.tldp.org/ and other places )
> 4. For an example algorithm in PHP which tests the validity of a UTF-8 string (and discards five / six octet sequences) head to:
>      http://hsivonen.iki.fi/php-utf8/

See the documentation for a code sample and further information: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php#54805